# Vertical Alignment of multicol and image nested in minipage

Tags: minipage, alignment

I have been googling and trying the TeX Exchange to find a solution and I am unable to find one yet.  I would like to move my three columns (I, II and III) to be the same height as the image I have included in the minipage.  I have tried several things including {t T} in the declaration and have looked at the adjustment box with no improvement.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr, lastpage}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{
 left=.5in,
        right=.5in,
        top=1in,
        bottom=1in
 }
 \pagestyle{fancy}
 \chead{Topic 2.1 - 2.4 \\ The Definition of Derivative}
 \lhead{\large{Name:}\\ class period:}
 \rhead{AP Calculus BC \\ \textbf{Quiz 1}}
\lfoot{AP Calculus BC}
\cfoot{Page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}
\rfoot{Mr. Bennett}

\setlength{\columnsep}{2cm}

\begin{document}

    \section*{Quiz 1 \\ Topics 2.1-2.4 \\ Definition of Derivative }

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node at (0,0)[draw,fill=black,text=white]{\textbf{Part I. Multiple Choice}};
    \end{tikzpicture}

Circle the best answer for each problem.  Each problem is worth 2 points.   

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node at (0,0) [draw]{\textbf{You have 20 minutes}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
        
\rule{0.9\textwidth}{.5pt}


    \begin{enumerate}           
        \item In the figure to the right, the graph of the function \(f\left(x\right)\) is shown.  Arrange these values from \emph{smallest} to \emph{largest}. \\
                
        \begin{minipage}[t]{0.7\textwidth}  
            \begin{multicols}{3}
                I.  \(\dfrac{f\left(1\right)-f\left(.25\right)}{\dfrac{3}{4}}\)
                II. \(\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 1}\dfrac{f\left(x\right)-f\left(1\right)}{x-1}\)
                III. \(f\left(2\right)-f\left(1\right)\)
            \end{multicols}
        \end{minipage}
        \begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=2in]{graph1.png}
        \end{minipage}
            
                A. I, II, II  \\ 
                
                B. II, I, III \\
                
                C. III, I, II \\
                
                D. III, II, I \\
                        \rule{0.9\textwidth}{.5pt}      
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: If I understand correctly, you would like the top of the row of equations to be at the same height as the top of the plot.  Try adding the option `[t]` to the minipage that holds the plot,  It would also look nicer if the baselines of the three equations were uniform.  That could be accomplished by adding `\vphantom{\dfrac{\mathstrut}{\mathstrut}}` to the third one.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Adding [t] only moves the list of choices lower (aligns bottom). I will look at the \vphantom

Comment: Any news? Meanwhile I edit my answer and a little bit change lookout of your document. Is this what you looking for?

Comment: @Zarko I could not get them to line up until I just tried your updated code.  Thank you so much for your continued support

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, your question is not entirely clear to me. Where and how long should be rules? Something like this?

[image]

(red rules indicate page layout)

MWE, which generate above image is:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[hmargin=.5in,vmargin=1in]{geometry}
%--------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[export, demo]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}


\begin{document}

\section*{Quiz 1 \\ Topics 2.1-2.4 \\ Definition of Derivative }

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[fill,text=white]{\textbf{Part I. Multiple Choice}};
    \end{tikzpicture}

Circle the best answer for each problem.  Each problem is worth 2 points.

\medskip
\textbf{You have 20 minutes}

\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{.5pt}

    \begin{enumerate}
\item   In the figure to the right, the graph of the function \(f\left(x\right)\) is shown.  Arrange these values from \emph{smallest} to \emph{largest}.

\medskip
     \begin{minipage}{0.7\linewidth}
        I.  \ \(\dfrac{f\left(1\right)-f\left(.25\right)}{\dfrac{3}{4}}\)\hfil
        II. \ \(\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{f\left(x\right)-f\left(1\right)}{x-1}\)\hfil
        III.\ \(f\left(2\right)-f\left(1\right)\)\qquad

    \begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{\Alph*.},align=left, leftmargin=*]
    \item   I, II, II  
    \item   II, I, III 
    \item   III, I, II 
    \item   III, II, I 
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{minipage}\begin{minipage}{0.3\linewidth}
                          \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, valign=t]{graph1.png}
                  \end{minipage}
                    
\rule{\linewidth}{.5pt}

\item   Next question ...

\rule{\linewidth}{.5pt}
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```